# If $m | (8n +7)$, $m | (6n + 5)$, prove that $m = ± 1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, divisibility

If $m | (8n + 7)$, $m | (6n + 5)$,prove that $m = ± 1$

-We have just starting going over the "divides" notation, and I am aware of a few properties and theorems from my notes. I am; although, a bit lost as to how to properly set up this proof. Any help is appreciated.

So far I have:

$$3(8n + 7) - 4(6n + 5) = (24n + 21) - (24n + 20)$$

This equals 21 - 20 = 1, although I don't know how to prove for ± 1
(is it because the problem doesn't define $m \ge 1$?)

Comment: if $a|b$ and $a|c$, then $a| b-c$

Comment: So you have $m|1$.  Assuming m is an integer there are only two options.  m = 1 or m = -1.

Comment: Try to get a solution $(x,y)$ for $(8n+7)x+(6n+5)y=1$ this is equivalent to the fact that $(8n+7,6n+5)=1$ according to Bezout's theorem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $m\mid 8n+7$ and $m\mid 6n+5$, then $$m\mid 3(8n+7)-4(6n+5)=1,$$

so $1=mk$ for some $k\in\mathbb Z$, so $m=\pm 1$.

Comment: and $\gcd(3,4) = 1$

Comment: @SiXUlm You don't need to know that.

Comment: that would result in less reasoning. Otherwise, I can write: $m | 15(8n+7) - 20(6n+5) = 5$. What would you do then?

Comment: @SiXUlm I could only conclude $m\in\{-5,-1,1,5\}$, which wouldn't let me finish the problem. Here $\gcd(3,4)=1$ is a _consequence_ of the fact that $3(8n+7)-4(6n+5)=1$, but a consequence that we don't need to point out. If $m\mid a$ and $m\mid b$, then $m\mid ax+by$, no matter what $\gcd(x,y)$ is.

Comment: then from that possible set, how can you conclude that $\gcd(8n+7, 6n+5) = 1$ ? I mean, it would be better if we can reduce the possible set of values as small as possible.

Comment: If I got $m|5$ I'd have $m|6n$ and $m|2n + 2$ so I'd have $m|6$ so I'd have $m|6-5 = 1$.

Comment: @SiXUlm: you're not trying to conclude that $\gcd(8n+7, 6n+5) = 1$, but it follows from Bezout's lemma once you've written $3(8n+7)-4(6n+5)=1$. In any case, it's irrelevant as pointed out in user236182's comment: all you need is that $m$ divides $1$, which follows from the answer above.